# "Блокада Ленинграда" - Может ли определение быть существительным?

Tags: синтаксис

В предложении "Блокада Ленинграда продолжалась..." слово "Ленинграда" - это дополнение или определение?

Answer (score 1):

Ленинграда - несогласованное определение, которое может быть выражено существительным.

Определения несогласованные, в отличие от согласованных, связываются с определяемым словом по способу управления (стихи поэта, лодка с парусами) или примыкания (езда шагом, желание учиться). Они могут быть выражены существительными без предлогов (в родительном и творительном падежах) и с предлогами (во всех косвенных падежах): Легкий порыв ветра разбудил меня (Т.);

Подробнее о несогласованных определениях можете прочитать здесь: [Несогласованные определения](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook107/01/title.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Несогласованное определение может выражаться косвенными падежами существительного, но **думаю, что в данном случае это, скорее, дополнение.**

Дополнением считаются такие формы, которые имеют соответствие в глагольных сочетаниях: блокировать Ленинград - блокада Ленинграда (родительный объекта).

Да и естественный вопрос, который можно задать, - это блокада (чего?), а не блокада (какая?).

Также в некоторых учебниках подобные дополнения называются определительными, то есть они имеют добавочное определительное значение, кроме основного объектного.

Примеры несогласованных определений: книга (чья) брата, костюм в полоску, книжка с картинками.

Comment: Стихи поэта - можно задать вопрос: какие стихи?

Comment: Думаю, что нет. Ответ на такой вопрос: хорошие стихи, новые стихи и т.д. Мы говорим: это чье стихотворение? Стихотворение Пушкина.